# IInAppBillingService.aidl for In-app Billing version 5

Tags: android, in-app-billing, android-sdk-manager

According to version notes the In-app Billing version 5 was released on February 2015.
[Version Notes](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/versions.html)

I am having trouble finding the IInAppBillingService.aidl describing the updated interface.

I have updated Google Play Billing Library through SDK Manager to Rev. 5, but
the /extras/google/play_billing directory contains only IInAppBillingService.aidl describing interface without the new methods.

Is it not available yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the answer here:
[How to upgrade/downgrade subscriptions in Android InAppBilling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29915035/how-to-upgrade-downgrade-subscriptions-in-android-inappbilling)

One of the answers points to updated IInAppBillingService.aidl file:
https://gist.github.com/cre8ivejp/21b10fbbc7e500f99059

Answer (score -1):

if you upgraded Google Play Billing you are working with V5  should work right,you followed this example?

[Here](http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/preparing-iab-app.html)

Comment: Everything is working right, but IInAppBillingService.aidl does not have the new methods' signatures.

Comment: Actually this answer does not address the topic of the question at all - IInAppBillingService.aidl for In-app Billing version 5.