# How to upgrade/downgrade subscriptions in Android InAppBilling?

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I spent a week looking for solution to upgrade/downgrade subscriptions on Android **InAppBilling**.

There's a reference page about this function: http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html

Google said that we could use `getBuyIntentToReplaceSkus()` method, but I couldn't found any documentation about that in its signature. I can't also see it in **IInAppBillingService.aidl** file that Google provided.

Is there any one who may help me?

Answer (score 4):

Just use my aidl file and be happy :)

It works perfectly!

https://gist.github.com/cre8ivejp/21b10fbbc7e500f99059

*Do not change the order of the methods inside aidl file or it will not work.

Comment: @Solidus0815 as described in the documentation, the error happens because the getBuyIntentToReplaceSkus was implemented on api version 5 and not 3.
You just need to change the first parameter from **3** to **5** here
`mService.getBuyIntentToReplaceSkus(5, "package", subs,
       key, "subs", getResources().getString(R.string.developer_payload));`

Comment: @Solidus0815 I'm glad you made it :)

Comment: I used same code as `getBuyIntent` from IabHelper like this:

`Bundle buyIntentBundle = mService.getBuyIntentToReplaceSkus(5, mContext.getPackageName(), oldSkus, newSku, itemType, extraData);`


However 

`PendingIntent pendingIntent = buyIntentBundle.getParcelable(RESPONSE_BUY_INTENT);` pendingIntent is null.

Comment: @Shark are you using the aidl file that i post on gist?? If so, did you change something inside?

Comment: actually no. I mean yes... I was commenting for a coleague here, and he just told me 
"yes I did change it, and that's why it didn't work. Once I copy/pasted his, everything worked alright".

So, it's all working fine now (y) :)

Answer (score 1):

at first thanks for aidl file.

But for me it is not working. I always get an error code 5:

> Invalid arguments provided to the API. This error can also indicate
>   that the application was not correctly signed or properly set up for
>   In-app Billing in Google Play, or does not have the necessary
>   permissions in its manifest

I don't think that the permissions are wrong or it is not correctly signed as all
other payment requests work.

This is my code:

```
List<String> subs = new ArrayList<>();
subs.add(current_sub);
buyIntentBundle = mService.getBuyIntentToReplaceSkus(3, "package", subs,
       key, "subs", getResources().getString(R.string.developer_payload));
```

How do you execute an upgrade request or do you see any error in my request?

Thanks
Solidus

Comment: @gaijinboy thanks man, that was pretty stupid of me :D:D:D
finally everything is working as expected

Comment: In case someone is looking for what @gaijinboy said, follow this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29915035/how-to-upgrade-downgrade-subscriptions-in-android-inappbilling#comment52158082_31880778

Answer (score 1):

You just have to update the 'aidl' file from the official gitHub, and clean-build the project:

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-billing/blob/master/TrivialDrive/app/src/main/aidl/com/android/vending/billing/IInAppBillingService.aidl

You'll be happy forever after.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a mistake/bug from google. They have not updated aidl file correctly. You can probably add this method to aidl file yourself (and figure out correct signature by try&error) but if you can you should wait a little while they get their act together.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue and found out that

1. it is only supported in version 5
2. the position of new sku (the array list) and old sku should be changed. Even though the methods shows first old and then new.. make the other way.