# Ionic 3.x + Android: Exclude IInAppBillingService from com.adobe.creativesdk.image:4.6.3+ cordova plugin

Tags: android, duplicates, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, adobecreativesdk

I have an Ionic 3.x application that uses both **Adobe Creative SDK** & **cordova-plugin-inapppurchase** plugins.

**Problem #1**: When the project is built for android. It throws an error ***"com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/android/vending/billing/IInAppBillingService$Stub$Proxy.class".***

**Problem #1 SOLVED**: This compilation error is resolved by excluding a duplicate copy of IInAppBillingService.aidl (from cordova-plugin-inapppurchase), since it is already imported by Adobe Creative SDK plug-in. Following the instructions on [Adobe Creative SDK Q&A](https://creativesdk.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/209685473-Android-Image-Editor-IInAppBillingService-Stub-Proxy-class-duplicated-entry-Exception) solved it. Great!!

**Problem #2**: Adobe Creative SDK internally uses [Google In-App Billing V3](https://github.com/AlexDisler/cordova-plugin-inapppurchase/blob/master/src/android/billing/IInAppBillingService.aidl). Now, we want to use **In-App Billing V5 (that exposes subscription upgrade/downgrade functionality)**. Upgradation to v5 API can be achieved by customizing the aidl (interface class). Here is an [example](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-billing/blob/master/TrivialDrive/app/src/main/aidl/com/android/vending/billing/IInAppBillingService.aidl). Discussed with more details on [Stackoverflow Forum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29915035/how-to-upgrade-downgrade-subscriptions-in-android-inappbilling) and [Android Play Billing with Upgrade/Downgrade Subscription](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-billing/tree/551a178e52baf60cc6e1f9cb6f40767b8453655a/TrivialDrive/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/trivialdrivesample).

**PROBABLE SOLUTION for Problem #2**

1. **Include back, "IInAppBillingService.aidl"** in cordova-plugin-inapppurchase (that was earlier excluded while solving Problem #1).
2. **Customize this interface** and incorporate changes as implemented by Android developers that introduces the "getBuyIntentToReplaceSkus" service method in aidl (interface).
3. **Exclude** the entire **"com.android.vending.billing" package/framework** which is being internally imported by Adobe Creative SDK Cordova plugin.

Any help in solving this issue will be highly appreciated.

Comment: (1/3) When both Adobe Creative SDK & cordova-plugin-inapppurchase plugins are installed in an ionic app,it throws a conflict/duplication of IInAppBillingService.class stub during compilation/building. This compilation error is resolved by excluding a duplicate copy of IInAppBillingService.aidl (from cordova-plugin-inapppurchase), since it is already imported by Adobe Creative SDK plug-in. Recommended by Adobe Q&A forum: https://creativesdk.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/209685473-Android-Image-Editor-IInAppBillingService-Stub-Proxy-class-duplicated-entry-Exception

Comment: (2/3) Adobe Creative SDK internally uses Google In-App Billing V3. Now we want to use In-App Billing V5 (that exposes subscription upgrade/downgrade functionality). Upgradation to v5 API can be achieved by customizing the aidl (interface class). Here is the sample implementation - https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-billing/tree/551a178e52baf60cc6e1f9cb6f40767b8453655a/TrivialDrive/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/trivialdrivesample

Comment: (3/3) To customize aidl interface (for implementing v5 feature), we need to include back the IInAppBillingService.aidl in cordova-plugin-inapppurchase plugin and find a way out to get "com.android.vending.billing" package getting excluded from Adobe Creative SDK plugin.